# Is PNG bad for Browser Compatibility

Tags: image, png, cross-browser

I just figured out that if I make image .PNG its smaller than if I make it .JPG. Since I try my best to make fastest website I can size of the images are pretty important too. So my question is that I believe phones doesn`t support .PNG pictures. Is it true or not ? and Should I continue using .PNG instead .JPG ? Is there any solution that I can do in order to make smaller images without lowering their resolution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Old browsers like IE6 (which is now deprecated) don't support transparent PNG files, so it really depends on which browsers you plan to support. In general, PNG files are fine and will run on all major browsers. Unlike JPEGs, PNG is lossless and this may work against it at times when compressing. If the image is complex, it may be better to have it saved as a JPEG for better quality. There's a small table [here](http://www.digitalfamily.com/tips/Best-Image-Format.html) which briefly explains each format.
A tool I use for really compressing PNGs files is [PNG Monster](http://www.vbgore.com/PNG_Monster). This often gets a better compression than some graphics applications.

Comment: Exactly I just downloaded omg I compressed 6 png files it did very good job without lowering the quality of the picture awesome ! Thanks


Bytes before: 23956
Bytes after: 6463

Answer (score 1):

Apart from older versions of Internet Explorer, I'm not aware of any platform that doesn't support PNG.

Wikipedia: [Web browser support for PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Web_browser_support_for_PNG)

Answer (score 1):

Whether an image is smaller in JPEG or PNG depends on the image. For example, a large photo with no or few single-color area will compress better with JPEG. PNG compression is lossless which makes it more suitable for icons and similar things.

Every desktop browser nowadays supports both PNG and JPEG. Android and iOS, both using WebKit (AFAIK) do support it. So chose the format which suits the *image* best.

Answer (score 1):

.png images are much better for backgrounds and logos where .jpg images are much better for photographs. If you are trying to use animated images (which .jpg doesn't support), I recommend .gif (though I don't recommend them for normal images; that's why .png was created). Animated .gif images are supported on almost all devices, While animated .png (.apng) images are supported on most pc web browsers. If you would like to see how your website would render in another web browser (e.g. IPhone, PSP, android, etc.), you can use User Agent Switcher for Firefox (I don't know if it works with 4.0). To get more user agents you could probably just search something like "User Agents for User Agent Switcher" in Bing (or Google).

In my websites, I always use .png for images (background, favicon, logo, custom buttons, etc.) and .jpg for pictures (screenshots (sometimes), photos, etc.)

Comment: Agree except the .apng support you mentioned. Animated pngs are "NOT" supported on most browsers and neither is their support likely to improve. Hence should not be used. See compatibility chart [**here**](http://caniuse.com/apng). GIFs are still the way to go with animated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

PNG is good for "ICON", "THUMBNAIL", "TRANSPARENT IMAGES"

While JPG is good for "LARGE IMAGE", "SCREENSHOT", "PHOTOGRAPH"

GIF is good for "ANIMATION"

PNG is good for some browser. You can see the difference when you try to create image using php. PNG quality is better than JPG when you did that.

Comment: You shift key seems to be stuck, you might want to fix that.